# 100% height for content using sticky footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### Edit

I have update a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/kqhyr/1/) here for people to try. There is a working solution using javascript proposed by @Aspiring Aqib. (CSS only) solutions are still more than welcome.

### Original post

I managed to create a **sticky footer** using the following [description](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). The footer works perfectly. I am having problem creating a content div `.content` that sticks exactly between the header and the footer.

---

> *I have this so far* (`.content` in yellow):

[image]

> *And I can't manage to do this* (`.content` contained exactly between the header and the footer):

[image]

I have generated the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/kqhyr/1/).

Any ideas how this could be achievable?

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: Oups sorry, the link is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` is class name of that div. Remove `min-height` and `height` property from `.wrapper` div. And use:

```
.content {
    min-height:85%; // <--- 85% will be better.
    height:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: It will not push footer down. It is just a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry @Aspiring, I have updated the fiddle with what you said [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/kqhyr/1/). It doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Patt remove `min-height` and `height` property from `.wrapper` div. And see my updated answer.

Comment: Sure, I am trying this. I am struggling like crazy :( Thanks for your help @Aspiring.

Comment: Oups, the footer does not stick to the bottom now :( Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/kqhyr/3/). I guess this problem is harder than it looks..:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25413/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-patt)

Comment: Hey @Aspiring, I found a CSS only solution! I'll post it asap. I have accepted your answer for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set height of your *content* div. Just add:

```
.content {
  height: 85%
}
```

There's fiddle: http://cssdesk.com/xNFEB

Comment: If you download and try it (top-right corner), it doesn't work in the any browser. Any ideas why?

Comment: It work just fine for me or I just don't understand the problem. What is wrong with top right corner?

Comment: So, if you download the cssdesk file in your computer, it will not work. That's why it's actually better to use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/kqhyr/1/). Sorry about that.